# Chaining joins in SQL based on dynamic table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, hive

The title may not be accurate for the question but here goes!  I have the following table:

```
id1    id2    status
1      2      a
2      3      b
3      4      c
6      7      d
7      8      e
8      9      f
9      10     g
```

I would like to get the first `id1` and last `status` based on a dynamic chain joining, meaning that the result table will be:

```
id    final_status
1     c
6     g
```

Logically, I want to construct the following arrays based on joining the table to itself:

```
id1    chained_ids    chained_status
1      [2,3,4]        [a,b,c]
6      [7,8,9,10]     [d,e,f,g]
```

Then grab the last element of the `chained_status` list.

Since if we were to keep joining this table to itself on `id1 = id2` we would eventually have single rows with these results.  The problem is that the number of joins is not constant (a single `id` may be chained many or few times).  There is always a 1 to 1 mapping of `id1` to `id2`.

Thanks in advanced! This can be done in either T-SQL or Hive (if someone has a clever map-reduce solution).

Comment: The right term for this is "Recursive Query". Is this MS sql-server?

Comment: Either MS SQL-Server or Hive.

Comment: Why doesn't id 6 loop back onto ID 1? In other words, why isn't the result just: 6, c.

Comment: The final link for `id1` = 1 is 4, so we preserve the value of status for that row in the result.  Linkage does not exist between `id2` and `id1` when `id1` = 6.  They would be linked if there was another row containing id1 = 4 and id2 = 6

Comment: Heh, whoops, my fault. When I copy and pasted your data the 0 of the 10 got cut off, so in my test it looked like 9 (part of the 6 lineage) looped back to 1. Fixing that my test gives the correct results.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to test this now as well.  I haven't used this type of logic before, very elegant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a recursive CTE:

```
;WITH My_CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        id1,
        id2,
        status,
        1 AS lvl
    FROM
        My_Table T1
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM My_Table T2
            WHERE T2.id2 = T1.id1
        )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        CTE.id1,
        T3.id2,
        T3.status,
        CTE.lvl + 1
    FROM
        My_CTE CTE
    INNER JOIN My_Table T3 ON T3.id1 = CTE.id2
)
SELECT
    CTE.id1,
    CTE.status
FROM
    My_CTE CTE
INNER JOIN (SELECT id1, MAX(lvl) AS max_lvl FROM My_CTE GROUP BY id1) M ON
    M.id1 = CTE.id1 AND
    M.max_lvl = CTE.lvl
```

Comment: Hey Tom, I revised the answer to include the logic of constructing the list.

Comment: Nice solution.  Should the title of the post be changed?  I'm not sure my title is a good description of the question...

Comment: Up to you. I guess it depends on what other people in the future might look for. The usual terminology for your structure is a linked list table. Sometimes also called a hierarchy (although I consider those to be slightly more complex, with multiple children possible). The final SQL uses recursion. So, you're looking to get the leaf node of the hierarchy or the last item in a linked list for a given root.

Comment: You get a better plan when you change the final logic to ROW_NUMBER: `SELECT ...
FROM
 (
   SELECT
      ..., 
      ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER (PARTITION BY id1
            ORDER BY lvl DESC ) AS rn
   FROM My_CTE
 ) AS dt
WHERE rn = 1`. And hopefully there's no cycle...

Comment: I was trying to avoid going another layer deep in subqueries. If performance is an issue and that gives better performance in this case then it's certainly another way to do it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: SQL Server's optimizer is usually stupid and doesn't materialize the cte, it's actually calculating it twice.